# Sliding dropdown alert, how can I achieve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could somebody please give me a few pointers on how to add a sliding dropdown area onto my home page similar to the following website: http://laptop-repair-manchester.co.uk. (**Warning, trips for malware**)

The thing I would like to imitate is the dropdown area that reads "call for a free quotation", it displays after about 5 seconds of the page loading.

If possible I would also like to add an image to the drop down slide effect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That page is not working with me

Comment: The site is very slow loading for some reason :s

Comment: I edited your question with a warning, as the link you provided trips a malware warning on Chrome. Please feel free to remove it, whenever that is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be quite straight-forward since jQuery has a `.slideDown` function: http://jsfiddle.net/QWqj5/.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#alert").slideDown(2000); // slide duration of 2 seconds
}, 5000); // execute after 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, you can create a div at the top of your page containing all the information that you want and then apply JQuery's [slide down function](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) on this div.